Should ValueTask<T>Socket.SendAsync() return immediately or only after transmission is complete?
In the following C# .NET8 snippet, should the following ValueTask Socket.SendAsync() call return immediately or only after the transmission is complete?  On my system, the code snippet below returns from soc.SendAsync() immediately while the transmission continues in the background (verified by observing Wireshark traffic).  I did not expect this, and I don't see a lot of examples using SendAsync() that returns ValueTask.
What alternatives exists so the send method returns only after the transmission is complete?
using System.Net.Sockets;

private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    using Socket soc = new(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    await soc.ConnectAsync("127.0.0.2", 10001);

    byte[] byteArray = new byte[100_000];
    var mem = new ReadOnlyMemory<byte>(byteArray);

    // This SendAsync call returns immediately even though transmission continues in background.
    // Should this be awaited before returning bytesSent?
    int bytesSent = await soc.SendAsync(mem, SocketFlags.None);
}


It doesn't matter that this overload of SendAsync returns a ValueTask as opposed to Task. It's not what controls when it returns. I'm sure the other overloads return as soon as the bytes are sent, too.

What exactly is the distinction you're trying to make here? What does "transmission is complete" mean here? To the network driver? That is just a memory copy to a queue, it will be instantaneous. To the receiver? You will never get that kind of feedback.

Sync version might block if underlying outgoing queue is full (for example, receiver slowly handling incoming data). SendAsync doesn't block, it yields thread, intuitively.

My goal was to send data over a socket and have my code continue after the data was completely sent.  I incorrectly assumed this would happen at the await SendAsync() line.  When I single stepped over the SendAsync() line, execution returns immediately, but Wireshark traffic continues for several seconds after the command executes.  I could use the Socket.Send() command that blocks until completion, but is there a more efficient way to use SendAsync()?
